# matplotlib subfigures label placement

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a figure consisting of a 2x1 grid, where the left part contains a 3x3 subplot (with rows sharing y-axis) and the right part a 3x1 subplot. The following code aims to achieve this, but places titles and labels inside of other plots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15), constrained_layout=True)
subfigs = fig.subfigures(1, 2,  width_ratios=[3, 1])

axs0 = subfigs[0].subplots(3, 3)
# PLOT
for x in axs0:
    for y in x:
        y.plot([1,2], [0, 1])

subfigs[0].suptitle('Title 1')
subfigs[0].supxlabel('Sub 1')
subfigs[0].supylabel('Y 1')


axs1 = subfigs[1].subplots(3, 1)

# PLOT
for y in axs1:
    y.plot([0,1], [0, 1])

subfigs[1].suptitle('Title 2')
subfigs[1].supxlabel('Sub 2')
subfigs[1].supylabel('Y 2')

plt.show()
```

What's weird, is that when I change the first (or second) subplot to be of different size, (e.g 3x3 and 4x1) the titles are placed just fine.

[Example: Labels outside of plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJkBM.png)

[Example: Labels inside of plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxEme.png)

Also I get the following warning:

```
UserWarning: This figure was using constrained_layout, but that is
incompatible with subplots_adjust and/or tight_layout; disabling
constrained_layout.

  self.figure.tight_layout()
```

Which is strange, as I run a .py file containing just the code I provided.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: It's because `subfigs[0].supxlabel('Sub 2')` is on the wrong subfig. It should be on `subfigs[1]`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I fixed this small mistake, but this is not the main issue. I added some example plots to illustrate the problem.

Comment: I see, I can't reproduce the "labels inside of plots" issue. Here's what I get when I copy-paste your updated code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPQdX.png

Comment: Have you modified `rcParams` (or have a config file) that's setting a tight layout? Now I can [reproduce this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLy5z.png) if I manually add `plt.tight_layout()` before `plt.show()`, so maybe you are inadvertently setting a tight layout somewhere else.

Comment: Must be the case: I get the following 'UserWarning: This figure was using constrained_layout, but that is incompatible with subplots_adjust and/or tight_layout; disabling constrained_layout.
  self.figure.tight_layout()'.
Which is strange, as I run a .py file containing just the code I provided.